# Troubles with function calling

Tags: javascript, function, editor, call

I'm using [EditArea](http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/editarea) editor. There is function: `editAreaLoader.execCommand`, it receives id of editor and command with arguments. So the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Call go to line function after click at button
   $('#line_go').click(function() {
      console.log($('#line_to').val());
      editAreaLoader.execCommand('example_1', 'go_to_line', $('#line_to').val());
    });

    // Try to do the same but after loading of the page
    editAreaLoader.execCommand('example_1', 'go_to_line',$('#line_to').val() );
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="edit" name="line" id="line_to" value="15" /> 
<input type="button" name="line_go" id="line_go" value="Go" />
```

So, when the page loads nothing happens. But when I click at button editor goes to line #15 (or something else if I change it). `console.log` shows `15`.

When I wrap `execCommand` (second, which is called after page loading) with alert, for example, it returns false.

What's wrong is there? Why does call after page loading returns false? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `$(document).ready(...)` fires before your EditArea instance has finished initialising itself. When you fire the click event on `#line_go` it is after the EditArea instance has initialised and is therefore able to retrieve information about it or perform actions upon it.